# What is wrong with my program implementing a stack in C

Tags: c, data-structures, stack-overflow

Hi i have a problem with my stack data structure program. It seems that when i define the size of my array/the imaginary size of array just to call it through a loop the size i defined or specified by the user is being depleted or somewhat edited when i enter a data or push.

For ex. i entered 5 for the size and choose push and then add 2. It is working properly. But if i choose to push data again, it is now passing to the size variable. I do not know understand what is happening...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define p printf
#define s scanf

int top;
int ar[1];
int size;

main()
{
    void push();
    int opt, num;
    char cont[] = { 'y' };
    clrscr();

    p("Stacking Program");
    p("\n\nData Size: ");
    s("%d", &size);
    p("\n");

    while((cont[0] == 'y') || (cont[0] == 'Y'))
    {
        clrscr();
        p("Stacking Program");
        p("\n\nData Size: %d\n\n", size);
        p("MAIN MENU\n1. Pop\n2. Push\n3. Pick\n4. View\nChoose: ");
        s("%d", &opt);
        p("\n");

        switch(opt) {
            case 1:
                pop();
                break;
            case 2:
                if(top > size)
                {
                    p("You can't push more data");
                }
                else
                {
                    p("Enter data for Data[%d]: ", top);
                    s("%d", &num);
                    push(num);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                pick();
                break;
            case 4:
                view();
                break;
            default:
                p("Your choice is not in the list.");
                break;
        }

        p("\n\nDo you want continue\(Y\/N\)?");
        s("%s", &cont[0]);
    }
}

pop()
{
    int a;
    if(top < 0)
    {
        p("Stack empty.");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        a = ar[top];
        p("\(Data[%d] = %d\) removed.", top, a);
        top--;
    }
}
void push(int b)
{
    top++;
    ar[top] = b;
}
pick()
{
    if(top < 0)
    {
        p("Nothing to display.");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        p("\(Data[%d] = %d\) is the last data.", top, ar[top]);
    }
}
view()
{
    int i;
    if(top < 0)
    {
        p("Nothing to display.");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i = 1; i < (top + 1); i++)
        {
            p("Data[%d] = %d\n", i, ar[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You defined ar to be of size 1 - that is, it will only hold one element. When you enter more, it overflows and spills onto neighbouring variables and, ouch, code. Never ever forget a check on static array sizes.

Comment: Don't use stuff like `#define p printf`. It's not an efficient obfuscation, but it makes the code much less readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the size of the array at runtime, using the size entered by the user.
instead of:

```
int top;
int ar[1];
int size;
```

...

```
int top = -1;
int *ar = NULL;
int size = 0;
```

and then after getting size from the user:

```
   if ( size > 0 )
   {
      ar = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
      if ( ar == NULL )
      {
         printf("ERROR: malloc() failed\n");
         exit(2);
      }
   }
   else
   {
      printf("ERROR: size should be positive integer\n");
      exit(1);
   }


   ....
      p("\n\nDo you want continue(Y/N)?");
      s("%s", &cont[0]);
   }
   free(ar);


} // end of main
```

I think the for loop in view() should be:

```
 for(i = 0 ; i <= top ; i++)
```

also

```
case 2:
    if ( top == ( size - 1 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to dynamically size the array, another approach is to allocate an array with MAXSIZE elements, where MAXSIZE is "big enough". Also, some other comments:

You declared at the top of your program a character array of size 1:

```
char cont[] = { 'y' };
```

But in your scanf line later you try to use this:

```
s("%s", &cont[0]);
```

This will overflow your buffer even if the user types just one character, because %s assumes that the buffer has at least two bytes available, one for the character and one for the '\0'. Possible fix:

```
char cont[] = { 'y', '\0' };
// ...
s("%1s", cont);
```

Note that cont is the same and more common way of saying &cont[0].

Another problem is with things that might be caught by the compiler if warnings are turned on: all functions should be prototyped before they are mentioned, functions without explicit return type should be declared with type int, and you should not let a function drop off without returning a value even though you declared it to explicitly or implicitly. Also, '(' and ')' do not need to be escaped in string literals.

Here is a modified version with changes noted. I have redefined clrscr() because I don't have conio.h on this system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
// #include <conio.h>
#define clrscr() printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define p printf
#define s scanf

#define MAXSIZE 500


// prototypes [Changed]
int pop();
void push(int b);
int pick();
int view();

int top;
int ar[MAXSIZE];
int size;

int main()
{
    int opt, num;
    char cont[] = { 'y', '\0' }; // [Changed]
    clrscr();
    p("Stacking Program\n\n");

    // keep asking until we get a valid size [Changed]
    for (;;)
    {
        p("Data Size: ");
        s("%d", &size);
        if (size > 0 && size < MAXSIZE)
            break;
        printf("Not a valid size!\n");
    }
    p("\n");

    while((cont[0] == 'y') || (cont[0] == 'Y'))
    {
        clrscr();
        p("Stacking Program");
        p("\n\nData Size: %d\n\n", size);
        p("MAIN MENU\n1. Pop\n2. Push\n3. Pick\n4. View\nChoose: ");
        s("%d", &opt);
        p("\n");

        switch(opt) {
            case 1:
                pop();
                break;
            case 2:
                if(top > size)
                {
                    p("You can't push more data");
                }
                else
                {
                    p("Enter data for Data[%d]: ", top);
                    s("%d", &num);
                    push(num);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                pick();
                break;
            case 4:
                view();
                break;
            default:
                p("Your choice is not in the list.");
                break;
        }

        p("\n\nDo you want continue(Y/N)?");
        s("%1s", cont); // [Changed]
    }
    return 0;
}

int pop()
{
    int a;
    if(top == 0) // [Changed]
    {
        p("Stack empty.");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        top--; // [Changed]
        a = ar[top];
        p("(Data[%d] = %d) removed.", top, a);
        return a; // [Changed]
    }
}

void push(int b)
{
    ar[top] = b;
    top++; // [Changed]
}

int pick()
{
    if(top == 0) // [Changed]
    {
        p("Nothing to display.");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        p("(Data[%d] = %d) is the last data.", top, ar[top-1]); // [Changed]
        return -1; // [Changed]
    }
}

int view()
{
    int i;
    if(top < 0)
    {
        p("Nothing to display.");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i = 0; i < top; i++)  // [Changed]
        {
            p("Data[%d] = %d\n", i, ar[i]);
        }
        return -1;  // [Changed]
    }
}
```